# Связанные списки с помощью jQuery

Tags: jquery, списки, form

Делаю три зависимых друг от друга списка. Проблема в том, что onclick по содержимому p срабывает лишь в первом (главном - список марок) списке. В остальных он словно не видит элементы p - следовательно и событие onclick не срабатывает. Не пойму почему так и как это исправить?

Вид списков:

```
<form id='f'>
<div>
<span>Выберите марку</span>
<span class='select-wrap'>
<span data-value="marka" class='select-title'>Все<span></span></span>
<span class="select" id="sp-marka">
<p data-value="1">марка 1</p>
<p data-value="2">марка 2</p>
<p data-value="3">марка 3</p>
<input type="hidden" name="marka" id="marka" value="1" />
</span>
</span>
</div>
<div>
<span>Выберите модель</span>
<span class='select-wrap'>
<span data-value="model" class='select-title'>Все<span></span></span>
<span class="select" id="sp-model">
<p data-value="11">модель 1.1</p>
<p data-value="12">модель 1.2</p>
<p data-value="13">модель 1.3</p>
<input type="hidden" name="model" id="model" value="13" />
</span>
</span>
</div>
<div>
<span>Выберите раздел</span>
<span class='select-wrap'>
<span data-value="razdel" class='select-title'>Все<span></span></span>
<span class="select" id="sp-razdel">
<p data-value="131">раздел 1.3.1</p>
<p data-value="132">раздел 1.3.2</p>
<p data-value="133">раздел 1.3.3</p>
<input type="hidden" name="razdel" id="razdel" value="" />
</span>
</span>
</div>
<input id="search-form-submit-t" name="s" type="submit" value="Показать выбранное" class="search-form-submit">
</form>
```

С помощью jquery обрабатываю событие onclick каждого из p списков, таким способом реализовываю открытие и скрытие списка на подобе input-a типа select:

```
$('.select-title').next().find('p').click(function(){
var objParent = $(this).closest('span');
var id = objParent.prev().attr('data-value');
var value = $(this).attr('data-value');
$('#'+id).val(value).change(); 
objParent.prev().html($(this).text() + '<span></span>');
objParent.prev().toggleClass("active");
objParent.slideToggle();
});
```

и обрабатываю событие onchange каждого скрытого input-а, чтобы вывести следующий за ним список в соответствий с выбранным предыдущим:

```
$('input[type="hidden"]').change(function(){
var id = $(this).attr('name'); // атрибут name текущего (marka || model || razdel)
var value = $('#'+id+'').val(); // тек.знач
if (id=='marka') {
var idSelect = 'model';// id в который будем выводить список - следующий за текущим
var myArray = data[value]['child']; // массив выводимых данных
} 
if (id=='model') {
var val = $('#marka').attr('value'); //value первого элемента
var idSelect = 'razdel';// id в который будем выводить список - следующий за текущим
var myArray = data[val]['child'][value]['child']; // массив выводимых данных
} 
if (value > 0) {
var str = '';
for (var key in myArray) { 
str += '<p data-value="'+myArray[key]['id']+'">'+myArray[key]['name']+'</p>'; 
}
str += '<input type="hidden" name="'+idSelect+'" id="'+idSelect+'" value="" />';
$("#sp-"+idSelect).html(str);
}
});
```

Comment: Всё срабатывает: http://jsfiddle.net/H7E9m/1/

Comment: со статичными списками да все работает как надо - но если выгружать данные из массива с помощью скрипта и записывать их в список два или три, то клик не выполняется

Comment: а у меня тут и идет такой способ заполнения второго и третьего списка - статичный список здесь только первый - остальные зависят от выбранного первого

Comment: Спасибо, помогло))))

Comment: @ЛеМарк преобразовал комментарий в ответ. Если он верный, то отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подумай, почему динамически добавленные <p> у тебя не кликаются? Наверно потому что скрипт отработал, поставил существующим параграфам событие и всё. Тут нужен другой подход:

Попробуй вешать событие вот так:

```
$('.select-title').next().on('click', 'p', function(){...
```

И почитай вот это (делегированная обработка): http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/On